# C'est/il/elle est magnifique?

Tags: choix-de-mot, pronoms, pronoms-personnels

I want to say that a video of a dance is magnificent.

My first, naive, thought was to use *c'est magnifique* but I now think *Il est magnifique* might be better. The subject of the video is a girl dancing so should I use *Elle est magnifique* instead?

I want the subject of the sentence to be the dance, not the girl.

Comment: *Une vidéo* feminine, that rules out using *il*. In using *elle* you must make sure it is clear you're referring to the video and not to the girl in the video. Spontaneously *magnifique* will be thought to apply the girl so using *ce* would be better. I would not use *magnifique* for a video (but I would for a girl !). For a video, according to the situation, I'd rather use *super*, *géniale*, *vraiment très bien*, *remarquable*, *extraordinaire*.

Comment: Si j'ai bien compris, c'est la danse qui est à qualifier de magnifique, pas la vidéo.

Answer (score 4):

The simplified rule: if you are refering to a **specific** person or thing, use "il/elle". Otherwise, use "c'est".

---

- If the video is wonderful, you should say: "C'est magnifique" because the video in which the dance is beautiful and the girl dances well is **globally** wonderful. You don't point anything being wonderful, but the whole thing is.
- If people already know that you are **specifically** talking about the video, you can
  say "Elle est magnifique". Example: someone comments the video and say "C'est une très belle vidéo". You could answer "En effet, elle est magnifique".

---

- If the girl who is dancing were to be wonderful, you could say without any context that "Elle est magnifique". Here you are **implicitely** talking about the girl because the two following conditions are met:

  - you wouldn't have said "C'est magnifique" to talk about the girl, because she's not an object. It is the same as in English when "It's wonderful" for a girl sounds strange.
  - the context doesn't say anything about what you are refering to, it means you point something/someone out.
- Note that you could say "C'est une fille très charmante".

Comment: Dans ton point "specifically", attention à l'interaction avec "clip video/videoclip(n,m)". Le demi-mot reste possible dans un tel contexte i.e. "elle est magnifique".